# Is it possible to wait until all javascript files are loaded before executing javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have several JavaScript files which we load at the bottom of the master page. However, I have the situation that I need to perform some JavaScript before the other scripts are loaded. Is it possible to wait till all the JavaScript files are loaded and then execute some JavaScript code?

I thought `$(document).ready()` did this, but as it turns out, it doesn't. Of course we can move the script files from the bottom to the top, but I am wondering if it's possible what I want.

Comment: You can use a `script` loader to do it after you do your own script.

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you want - you talk, at the same time, of both wanting to perform X *before* other scripts are loaded, but also wanting to wait until all scripts *are* loaded. Which is it? And what is the nature of the X that you wish to perform?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever TGo be more clear: I want to execute javascript after all javascript files are loaded.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

You can use

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Which will wait until the page is loaded. `$(document).ready()` waits until the DOM is loaded.

In plain JS:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // your code here
})
```

Comment: Here is a better explanation http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/

Comment: Worked well for my application which needed to wait until dynamically loaded scripts were finished loading before generating page content. +1

Comment: The plain old JavaScript equivalent is: `window.addEventListener('load', function() { /* your code here */ })`.

Comment: does this appends the execution stack or replaces the old one?

Answer (score 37):

You can use [`.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and run your code after it loads:

```
 $.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){

    alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    // here you can use anything you defined in the loaded script

 });
```

You can see a better explanation here: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file)

Comment: if i want the standard javascript function, not jquery. how's the code?

Comment: Note that this will not cache the file, it will download it every time. The documentation refers to $.ajaxSetup or $.ajax to enable cache.

Comment: What if I'm LOADING jquery?

Answer (score 35):

You can use `<script>`'s `defer` attribute. It specifies that the script will be executed when the page has finished parsing.

```
<script defer src="path/to/yourscript.js">
```

A nice article about this: http://davidwalsh.name/script-defer

Browser support seems pretty good: http://caniuse.com/#search=defer

Another great article about loading JS using defer and async: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Comment: It does not seem to wait for all other JS files to have executes, at least not in Firefox.

Comment: Like the doc says, defer script loads when the page is parsed (instead of when js/css is loaded). This ain't a solution.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding a bit on @Eruant's answer,

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Works very well with both `async` and `defer` while loading on scripts.

So you can import all scripts like this:

```
<script src="/js/script1.js" async defer></script>
<script src="/js/script2.js" async defer></script>
<script src="/js/script3.js" async defer></script>
```

Just make sure `script1` doesn't call functions from `script3` before `$(window).on('load' ...`, make sure to call them inside `window load` event.

More about async/defer [here](https://bitsofco.de/async-vs-defer/).

Answer (score 0):

Thats work for me:

```
var jsScripts = [];

jsScripts.push("/js/script1.js" );
jsScripts.push("/js/script2.js" );
jsScripts.push("/js/script3.js" );

$(jsScripts).each(function( index, value ) {
    $.holdReady( true );
    $.getScript( value ).done(function(script, status) {
        console.log('Loaded ' + index + ' : ' + value + ' (' + status + ')');                
        $.holdReady( false );
    });
});
```