# how to wait for css when using icons in openlayers markers

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome, openlayers-3

In openlayers (v4.6.4) when I'm using font-awesome as marker icons, they don't show up at first load (empty cache and hard reload). All I see is a rectangle, like a broken character.
At the second load they appear perfectly.

[image: broken fontawesome icon in openlayers]

```
    var mapMarkerIcon = new ol.style.Style({
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            text: '\uf041 ', // <-- fa marker unicode
            font: 'Normal ' + 24 + 'px ' + 'FontAwesome',
            textBaseline: 'bottom',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: green,
            })
        })
    });
```

I guess this is because openlayers draws the unicode icon code before font-awesome css had the chance to load. At the second refresh, the page cached the css and that's why it works.

I can't ask all my users to refresh one time. Has someone any idea how to solve this problem?

Can I force the JS to wait for css?

I'm thinking that I only need one icon for the moment (the map-marker).
Maybe I can just load this one to make it faster? (I guess even then there is no guarantee to have the css before the JS runs)

Can I add a little piece of javascript to redraw the icons after a few ms or something?

Comment: Hey try using `Window: load event` function. This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit dirty, but maybe you want to implement a check like described in http://allthingssmitty.com/2016/09/12/checking-if-font-awesome-loaded/.
As soon as that returns true, you initialize your map.

P.S. Is there a specific reason that you use an icon font? Why don't you use an SVG icon?

Comment: I will try to switch to SVG, seems a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to get away with redrawing the map using `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){ map.render(); }, 1000);
```

Though it's probably best to use something that waits for everything to load before drawing.  See the top answer here if you can use jQuery here [Is it possible to wait until all javascript files are loaded before executing javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258068/is-it-possible-to-wait-until-all-javascript-files-are-loaded-before-executing-ja)

Comment: I just tried that and also redrawing vectorLayer but it doesn't work. Thanks for the idea though, it could have worked.