# Howto get Mailchimp pop-up to work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, django, google-chrome, popup, mailchimp

I seem to be having trouble getting the Mailchimp pop-up subscribe function to work on Chrome:

I added the following code to my index.html page in django:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us19.list-manage.com","uuid":"4eccd5a19349953c3e023b61d","lid":"9b2e4611ac","uniqueMethods":true}) })
</script>
```

Seems to be working fine in Opera, Firefox and IE but in Chrome I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: window.dojoRequire is not a function.**

What am I missing to make this work in Chrome?

Additional info:

- Python 3.6.1
- Django 2.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue and I figured out what went wrong: **ad blockers**.

Ad blockers prevent MailChimp popup signup form from showing up on your website. More precisely, an ad blocker prevents the Mailchimp JS script from loading which causes the `Uncaught TypeError: window.dojoRequire is not a function` error.

Bottom line: if a user is not using an ad blocker, the popup form would show up just fine. But if you want to make sure ALL users see the popup, create your own custom popup instead (using Bootstrap Modal, for example) and sign a user to MailChimp via the MailChimp API.

Comment: Did anyone else find this to be a helpful answer? Turning ad-blokers off does not fix this problem.

Comment: No turning off the ad blocker didn't solve the problem for me either.

Comment: I have the same issue while testing on Chrome as Guest (so no there are no extensions or ad blockers.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to wait for the first script to download and run, which creates the dojoRequire function. The second script is using the function before it has been created by the first. You can use a setTimeout() = yuck, or look for ways on stackoverflow to wait for the page to load, such as [Wait until Javascript files are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11258068/is-it-possible-to-wait-until-all-javascript-files-are-loaded-before-executing-ja/11258137)

Answer (score 0):

My issue was  the "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" firefox extension was blocking it, not my ad blocker.